# When I go through my answered question the tag shows "tagged null"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I have noticed that when I go through my profile answers and click on a tag (apache-spark in this case) the header shows that I'm looking for my answer tagged "null"

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.1.

The results are still good, I just built the title using a variable before it was assigned.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thanks for the quick reply ! :-)